# What is a Heuristic Function

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Can someone explain in very simple words what it is. Also provide an example. So for example if u have to find the heuristic function of something how is it supposed to look like?

Take as an example the problem:

For the water jug problem  http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/hollywood/diehard/diehard.htm

Devise and explain an admissible heuristic function (h) [not the trivial h(n) = 0]. The cost of an action is defined as 1 unit for performing the action, an additional 1 unit for moving each gallon of water (fill,
empty, pour), and an additional 1 unit for wasting
each gallon of water (empty). The path cost (g) is
the sum of the cost of all the actions.

Answer (score 13):

A heuristic function, is a function that calculates an *approximate* cost to a problem (or ranks alternatives).

For example the problem might be finding the shortest driving distance to a point.  A heuristic cost would be the straight line distance to the point.  It is *simple and quick* to calculate, an important property of most heuristics.  The true distance would likely be higher as we have to stick to roads and is much harder to calculate.

Heuristic functions are often used in combination with search algorithms.  You may also see the term *admissible*, which means the heuristic never overestimates the true cost.  *Admissibility* can be an important quality and is required for some search algorithms like A*.

Answer (score 2):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_function)

> A heuristic function, or simply a heuristic, is a function that ranks
>   alternatives in search algorithms at each branching step based on
>   available information to decide which branch to follow.

I.e. in chess, a Heuristic Function can rule out possible moves that will lead to a worse position (or even loss) for a player and not further analyze the following moves since the result will not get any better.

Doing so the function can search more moves in a shorter time period since it doesn't waste time looking at bad moves.

Comment: How do I find one for an asked problem?

Comment: Depends on a problem. A good heuristic function for cooking is tasting and comparing with memories of trying the same thing before. One for staying on the road is distance of car to the center of the lane you decided to be on. But any given problem can have different heuristic functions. For example, in a maze, you could try tracking your coordinates, or you could be trying to always go left, or if you think the maze builder is particularly sadistic, you could always try the path that seems to be taking you away from the exit (although that one is likely to backfire often).

Comment: Find one what? Heuristic Function? There are plenty of algorithms utilizing heuristics. A*, Alpha Beta pruning, etc.

Comment: You should try to solve the assignment youself. If you get stuck with a *specific* problem then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Heuristic function use to calculate the estimated cost  of problem. Heuristic function for sliding - tiles puzzles called Manhattan distance. Heuristic function denoted by h(n). A number of algorithms make use of heuristic function including heuristic search, A* algorithm, IDA(iterative deepening-A*).

Answer (score 0):

Heuristics Function h(n) tells an estimate of the minimum cost from any vertex n to the goal.Based on the problem we choice the heuristic function, remember that selection of the heuristics funtion is gives true result on all nodes.
For more details visit this website: http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html

Answer (score 0):

To determine the heuristic function, go through the traditional chess problem. generally, chess uses the combination of an algorithm to decide next move. head over to this link. i think it's the example you're looking for.
[Understand Heuristic Search with Chess](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/simple-chess-ai-step-by-step-1d55a9266977)

Answer (score 0):

Human evolutionary behavior is linked to cognitive and hearing intelligence, therefore, the heuristic paths are the easiest
approximations. The instant responses are further processed with our inherent logic or elementary learning through our experiential knowledge. So Heuristic Approximation algorithms
support our instant conclusions.