# How to get value of child node in minmax algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am working on minmax algorithm and i want to do alpha-beta pruning...
And i read one example having this tree.

[image: Tic Tac Toe tree]

i didnt understand , how to get value of child node, marked in red color.[image: Tic Tac Toe Tree]

can someone pls help me, how the values 3,5,10,2 come from and what is logic behind it ??

Comment: These values come from an evaluation function which will evaluate a state without looking any deeper. You need to provide this function. The values you see there are some example values returned by that evaluation function.

Comment: can u pls explain with an example, i am very much new to AI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't come from anywhere, usually, you *predict* those values.

For searching a tree with huge possible number of states (i.e chess game), this technique, also commonly known as [heuristic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137239/what-is-a-heuristic-function), is a must. A heuristic function usually takes a single parameter, a state i.e one of those child nodes (an array of size 9 for a tic-tac-toe game for example) and tries to predict how *favorable* this state is for a certain player. So, if the function is written from say, white's POV in chess, +10 might mean white is likely to win, while a -7 might mean game is in black's favor. A state where white is guaranteed to win, should have +infinity as returned value.

Naturally, questions like "how favorable" can't have a science-y, absolute answer. So you usually apply your intuition, domain expertise, common sense etc to write this function.

When number of states isn't huge, as in tic-tac-toe game for example, where you don't have to stop the search after certain depths, You can simply use +1,0,-1 to denote win, draw,loss respectively.

Comment: your answer was really helpful , can u pls send me some reference links which can help me to understand heuristic functions well..?

Comment: [go here](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/ai/alpha-beta-pruning), click on any problem e.g domineering or mancala, now go to "Discussions" tab....

Comment: Thanks a lot , it really helped